# run python script from cmd with inputs

Tags: python

I have written these lines of code to get input from user:

```
uname=os.environ.get( "USERNAME" )
pwd = getpass.getpass()
path=input("Provide TextFile Input: " )
```

I want to execute PythonApplication1.py from cmd. Please guide me.I am using python 3.6.

Comment: `python PythonApplication1.py`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to run your program with windows command line, so you need to add Python to system PATH variable or change your directory to Python's directory.

Type `python` in cmd and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, If Python comes up, Your `PATH` is ok! then you can run your program with this:

```
python your_program_path/Application1.py
```

Else if Python wasn't in your `PATH`, you can add it:
`Computer -> System Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment variables` or you can change your working directory to Python's directory:

```
cd c:\python_path
```

And then:

```
python your_program_path/Application1.py
```

Comment: I typed python "D:\python scripts\PythonApplication1.py" and got this following msg :File "<stdin>",line1 syntax error:invalid syntax. So i tried typing only "D:\python scripts\PythonApplication1.py"  and i didnt get any error

Comment: i have used this in the firts line of  py script :#!/usr/bin/python and the python.exe path is this C:\Users\aa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32.Is this creating any issue?

Comment: I think you was in python interpreter and then try to run it. close it, run cmd again

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python` used for Linux, not windows! remove it and try again.

Comment: nop not working.... i even tried in IDLE env,still not working.but if i open the script and press F5,it works